# How to draw a picture with a py file

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory

When I ran a python file to draw a picture using matplotlib on google colab notebook,it showed <'Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes'>

This is the code !python /content/sample_data/test.py

Python code in test.py is below:

```
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

x = np.arange(1,11) 
y =  2  * x +  5 
plt.title("Matplotlib demo") 
plt.xlabel("x axis caption") 
plt.ylabel("y axis caption") 
plt.plot(x,y) 
plt.show()
```

Anyone had the same issue before?

Comment: A cell in Jupyter notebook is running `IPython.display.display(_)` on your output (kind of). In the case of `matplotlib.pyplot` there is an extension that is telling what to do. If an extension is not working, figure out how to relaod it.

Comment: Thanks for help..So what should I do to draw a figure with py file on in Jupyter notebook?

Comment: So you are in your browser on the page served by Jupyter notebook and you have a `.ipynb` page, wherein you are running a `.py` file as a bash with an absolute path? If so, you have to use the `.savefig` as a `PIL.Image` will not be passed via bash or better, skip the madness and `import sample_data.test` in a regular `code` unmagical cell (or wherever it is relative to `__file__`).